# Getting the AVG in a single query that is GROUP BY in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need help in some query I'm working on.

So I have this query.

```
SELECT EventCode, COUNT(SchedStatus) as 'SchedStatus' 
                        
FROM itemschedule WHERE SchedStatus = 26 AND ActualTime <= SchedDateTime 
                        
GROUP BY EventCode ORDER BY COUNT(SchedStatus)
```

And the result is

```
EventCode   SchedStatus
Station1      3
Station2      1
Station3      1
```

And then I have this query

```
SELECT EventCode, COUNT(SchedStatus) as 'SchedStatus', COUNT(SchedStatus) / (SELECT COUNT(*) 

FROM itemschedule WHERE EventCode = "Station1") as 'Percentage'

FROM itemschedule WHERE SchedStatus = 26 AND ActualTime <= SchedDateTime AND EventCode = "Station1"
```

And the result is

```
EventCode  SchedStatus Percentage
Station1     3         0.0492
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get the average of each "EventCode" base on how many their "Schedstatus" is and dividing it to the total count of "SchedStatus".

So the result that I want is this.

```
EventCode   SchedStatus  Percentage
Station1      3           0.0492
Station2      1           "Average Here"
Station3      1           "Average Here"
```

But I cant make it to work because of the where clause that need the specific EventCode value.
Is there a way to get all the average based on the "EventCode" values in a single query?

Thank you to all who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution.

Hope this will help someone with the same case as mine.

```
SELECT d1.EventCode, COUNT(d1.SchedStatus) as 'SchedStatus', 

COUNT(d1.SchedStatus) / (SELECT COUNT(d2.SchedStatus) from itemschedule d2 WHERE d2.EventCode = d1.EventCode) as "Percentage"

FROM itemschedule d1 WHERE d1.SchedStatus = 26 AND d1.ActualTime <= d1.SchedDateTime

GROUP BY d1.EventCode ORDER BY COUNT(d1.SchedStatus) DESC
```

As you can see. I put an alias in the table I'm querying in and another alias in the subquery to get the data row with the same EventCode.

```
COUNT(d1.SchedStatus) / (SELECT COUNT(d2.SchedStatus) from itemschedule d2 WHERE d2.EventCode = d1.EventCode) as "Percentage"
```